# RunTime Error 2471: Expression as Query Parameter Producing Error

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a sub in Access 2010 that references a query. They're supposed to run through three columns and find the lowest one. When I run it, I get an error: "The expression you entered as a query parameter produced this error: 'Projects.ProjectID'

Sub:

```
Private Sub UpdatePriority_Click()
Overall_Priority = DMin("MinvonGeoPri", "qryOverallPriority", "Projects.ProjectId=1")
End Sub
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
     Min(Projects.GeoPavePri) AS MinvonGeoPri
,    Min(Projects.StrPri) AS MinvonStrPri
,    Min(Projects.SOPri) AS MinvonSOPri
,    Projects.ProjectId
FROM 
     Projects
WHERE
     Projects.ProjNo=Activity.ProjNo;
```

Google suggested that I add quotations around 1, so I changed it to `"Projects.ProjectID=" & 1 & ""`, but it didn't help. I've double checked spelling, field names, and I'm running out of ideas. Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have created a `qryOverallPriority` from the select statement, referencing the `Projects.[ProjectId]` field is simply `[ProjectId]`. In short, you lose the ability to reference the parent table although it could be referenced as `qryOverallPriority.[ProjectId]` but that is not necessary..

```
Private Sub UpdatePriority_Click()
    Overall_Priority = DMin("MinvonGeoPri", "qryOverallPriority", "ProjectId=1")
End Sub
```

Any field pulled by a saved query is referenced by how that save query sees it, not from the underlying SQL select statement that made up the saved query. Likewise, aliased fields would be referenced by their aliases; e.g. [ProjectId] and [ProjectId2] for both [ProjectId] fields in a join.

You are also using the aggregate `MIN` function without a `GROUP BY` clause. Use the Access front end to make sure that you are getting the results you want. Perhaps something like,

```
SELECT 
     Min(p.GeoPavePri) AS MinvonGeoPri
    ,Min(p.StrPri) AS MinvonStrPri
    ,Min(p.SOPri) AS MinvonSOPri
    ,p.ProjectId
FROM 
     Projects p
WHERE
     p.ProjNo=Activity.ProjNo;
GROUP BY p.GeoPavePri, p.StrPri, p.SOPri, p.ProjectId
```

You should be able to use,

```
Overall_Priority = DLookup("MinvonGeoPri", "qryOverallPriority", "ProjectId=1")
```

That is untested. I have not built a full test environment and I have no idea where `Activity.ProjNo` comes from.

Comment: So I got rid of `ProjectID` altogether, since it turns out it doesn't actually exist outside of this query, but it isn't grabbing the lowest value from GeoPri.

Comment: I was wondering about that. The underlying SQL statement should likely incorporate a `GROUP BY` statement to achieve the correct results. Use the Access front end to fine tune it so that you are achieving the correct results.